# Prevent scrolling from section, but allow anchor navigation in Fullpage.js

Tags: fullpage.js

My first fullpage.js section is scrollable (`scrollOverflow: true`), and I don't want a jump to the second section when reaching the bottom of the first section.

As such, I set up the following callback:

```js
onLeave: function(origin, destination, direction) {
    if (origin.index === 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is, this also prevents regular anchor links (such as `<a href="#section2">`) to work: navigation is also blocked by the callback.

This is annoying as my first page has links to the other sections.

**Is there a way to prevent `onLeave` only when it is due to a scroll, but still allow anchor navigation?**

The callback parameters do not seem to have a way to distinguish a scroll from an anchor click.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to prevent onLeave only when it is due to a scroll, but still allow anchor navigation?

Sure!
You can use the method `fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(false)` when reaching that section with scrollOverflow.

Then set it back to true in any other section:

```
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'orange'],
    navigation: true,

    onLeave: function(origin, destination, direction) {
        //assuming section 2 is the one with scrollOverflow
        fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(destination.index !== 1);
    }
});
```

Reproduction online:
https://jsfiddle.net/alvarotrigo/zx05cfr9/1/